# CountryData gives different answer depending on syntax

Tags: curated-data

Can anyone tell me why the GDP property of CountryData would be different because of syntax?

```
{QuantityMagnitude[CountryData["NewZealand", "Population"]] == 
  QuantityMagnitude[ Entity["Country", "NewZealand"]["Population"]],
 QuantityMagnitude[CountryData["NewZealand", "GDP"]] == 
  QuantityMagnitude[ Entity["Country", "NewZealand"]["GDP"]]}
(* {True, False} *)
```

Answer (score 7):

It appears that, as of this writing, [`CountryData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CountryData.html) is out of date.

```
CountryData["NewZealand", "GDP", "Date"]
```

> ```
> 2014
> ```

Whereas

```
EntityValue[Entity["Country", "NewZealand"], "GDP", "Date"]
```

> ```
> DateObject[{2016}, "Year", __]
> ```

That being said, it seems that `CountryData` and [`Entity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Entity.html) `"Country"` have some other differences.

```
CountryData["NewZealand", "GDP"]
```

> ```
> $ 1.9997*10^11 per year
> ```

but

```
EntityValue[
 Entity["Country", "NewZealand"], 
 EntityProperty["Country", "GDP", {"Date" -> DateObject@{2014}}]]
```

> ```
> $ 2.00696*10^11 per year
> ```

Even when specifying other `"CurrencyUnit"`s `Entity` `"Country"` does not return `CountryData`'s value for 2014.

```
cu = "CurrencyUnit" /. 
   EntityValue[EntityProperty["Country", "GDP"], "QualifierValues"];

EntityValue[
    Entity["Country", "NewZealand"], 
    EntityProperty["Country", "GDP", 
     {"Date" -> DateObject@{2014}, "CurrencyUnit" -> #}]
] & /@ cu // Column
```

> ```
> $ 1.62376*10^11 per year
> Missing[NotAvailable]
> $ 225351398500 per year
> $ 241926000000 per year
> $ 2.00696*10^11 per year
> ```

Since `Entity` `"Country"` has a `"Source"` annotation.

```
EntityValue[Entity["Country", "NewZealand"], "GDP", "Source"]
```

> ```
> Entity["Source", "WorldDevelopmentIndicatorsWorldBank"]
> ```

I would suggest using `Entity` `"Country"` as you know where the data is from with this option.  You can return the entire time series with

```
EntityValue[Entity["Country", "NewZealand"], 
 EntityProperty["Country", "GDP", {"Date" -> All}]]
```

Also, please report this issue to WRI.

Hope this helps.

*Well, after looking at `"Population"` I think it may be a case of `Entity` `"Country"` `"GDP"` being more recent. `"Population"` for both is for year 2014. However, this still does not explain why the 2014 `"GDP"` values don't agree between the two.*

Comment: Thanks - I have no idea how to file an issue with WRI.

Comment: @Joe Select *Help | Give Feedback ...* from the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Download CSV files from [`here`](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.MKTP.CD?view=map)

```
data = Import[
   "/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/API_NY/API_NY.GDP.MKTP.CD_DS2_en_csv_v2.\
csv"];

data[[1 ;; 3]]

(* {{"Data Source", "World Development Indicators", 
  ""}, {}, {"Last Updated Date", "2017-12-22", ""}} *)

nzGDP = DeleteCases[
   Transpose[{data[[5, 5 ;;]], 
     Select[data[[6 ;;]], #[[1]] == "New Zealand" &][[1, 
       5 ;;]]}], {___, _?(! NumericQ[#] &)}];

nzGDP[[-3 ;;]]

(* {{2014, 2.00696*10^11}, {2015, 1.75563*10^11}, {2016, 1.84969*10^11}} *)

ListPlot[Tooltip /@ nzGDP]
```

[image]

Comment: Why not just use `ts=EntityValue[Entity["Country", "NewZealand"], 
 EntityProperty["Country", "GDP", {"Date" -> All}]]; DateListPlot[ts, Joined->False]`?

Comment: @Edmund - There appeared to be some concern over the currency of the data so i went to the data source.